# All response data returns undefined in Ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

The Ajax call returns the following JSON:

[image]

Everything seems good. But when I try to access any of that content, it returns undefined.

```
success: function (respuesta){
   alert(respuesta.datos[0].cod_registro);
}
```

Even attributes like `status` or `success` return undefined. Any idea why that is? I'm not sure what I can post to help you.

Comment: respuesta.datos[0] is an object. So you have to loop. Something like respuesta.datos[0][0]

Comment: respuesta.datos is an array of arrays of objects, so you'd need respuesta.datos[0][0] to access the first object. The duplicate goes into detail how to iterate over such a structure

Comment: You're right. I can't believe that was the problem all along.

Answer (score 0):

`respuesta.datos` is an array of objects, so the syntax to access one of them should be something like `respuesta.datos[0].cod_registro`.

Comment: Ah, you're right. Dumb of me. I just edited the question, but essentially, that returns undefined too.

Comment: What does `console.log(respuesta.datos[0])` show?